# SQL select on parent child relation with multiple join conditions

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a parent/child relation with the following child table:

```
CHILD_ID    PARENT_ID    CHILD_VALUE
------------------------------
1           1            x
2           1            y
3           2            y
```

Now I want to select all existing distinct parents where the CHILD_VALUE is:

- child has value = x (there will be only 1 or none)
- if no child with value x exists - NULL

In other words show all parents with "matching" child or NULL if no child "matching" the value exists.

So the result shall look like this:

```
PARENT_ID    CHILD_ID    CHILD_VALUE
------------------------------
1            1           x
2            NULL        NULL
```

Question would be how I can narrow down the join in this case.

Comment: Can you explain what logic you are using for the "if no child with value x exists" case, the result CHILD_ID is `3` and not `2` or `NULL`?

Comment: I made a mistake in my result table, CHILD_ID for parent 2 has to be NULL of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does the trick:

```
select distinct a.parent_id, b.child_id, b.child_value
  from test1 a
  left outer join test1 b
               on a.parent_id = b.parent_id
              and b.child_value = 'x'
```

See also this [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e6683/3).

Comment: Thanks, the AND in the join did the trick. Was trying around with putting this into the WHERE part.